# domain for ln(x+y)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to find the domain of ln(x+y) deducing that it was y>-x and hence all the points in xy plane above the graph of -x. answer key says it is also the points under said graph without the -x itself included. how come?

Comment: Maybe this is the complex log?

Comment: no only real values

Comment: Then unless it is $\ln|x+y|$ or something like that, it's probably wrong. Do you mind posting the full context? Maybe there's something we're missing here.

Comment: no that is the entire question

Comment: Then it's probably best not to think about it. Maybe ask a professor about it, but it doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
if your function $z=\ln (x+y)$ is a real valued function, you know that, for teh value of the logarithm be real, you must have the argument $> 0$, so you must have $x+y > 0$.